# Getting total cpu percentage of virtual machine is always zero

Tags: c#, performancecounter, hyper-v

I am trying to get the total cpu usage every x seconds on our virtual machines. I found this code:

```
  var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true);

   WriteCpuUsageToFile(cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%");
```

Every time the timer fires, I am getting a value of zero.

```
2016-03-15T02:29:26 0%
2016-03-15T02:29:45 0%
2016-03-15T02:30:05 0%
2016-03-15T02:30:25 0%
2016-03-15T02:30:45 0%
```

The server is hitting an average of 20%.

I am allocating ~8 cores to the vm, depending on the vm. Do I need to get the value for a virtual machine differently with C#?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: You haven't said if the VM is doing anything. Also, what happens if you leave [`NextValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) as a `float`?

Comment: @WaiHaLee I've updated the post. I changed it to where it is not converting it at all and it's still zero.

Comment: The *first* time you call NextValue() on this counter you will always get 0.  It has not collected any data yet.  So using new PerformanceCounter() is quite wrong, you must only create it once, outside of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

While the old answer is interesting, it didn't solve the OP's question.

The problem (found in some screenshot in the comments) was that the OP was instantiating the `PerformanceCounter` every time he called `NextValue`, so it wasn't letting the counter collect the values.

The correct solution is instantiating the `PerformanceCounter` **once**, and call `NextValue()` many times on the same instance.

Old answer kept below for the hopefully interesting information, but it applies to the **host**, not to the **guest**:

---

As explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768535(v=bts.10).aspx

> **Measure guest operating system processor utilization** – Traditionally, processor performance can be measured using the “\Processor(*)\% Processor Time” performance monitor counter. This is not an accurate counter for evaluating processor utilization of a guest operating system though because Hyper-V measures and reports this value relative to the number of processors allocated to the virtual machine.

*... (lengthy explanation on why it's not a good idea and can actually be a bottleneck, which you can read on the link) ...*

> To accurately measure the processor utilization of a guest operating system, use the “\Hyper-V Hypervisor Logical Processor(_Total)\% Total Run Time” performance monitor counter on the Hyper-V host operating system. Use the following thresholds to evaluate guest operating system processor utilization using the “\Hyper-V Hypervisor Logical Processor(_Total)\% Total Run Time” performance monitor counter

<strike>So I haven't tested this, but</strike>

***Edit:*** I actually tested it and it works, so:

```
var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Hyper-V Hypervisor Logical Processor"
        , "% Total Run Time"
        , "_Total", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, that actually gave me some other information I was looking for. As for the code, I am getting this when I try to run it `Category does not exist.`

Comment: @ErocM I just tested the code in a hyper-v Windows Server 2012 guest and it works for me. It gives the same values as the "Total" cpu in the task manager

Comment: It gives me a `Category does not exist` exception if I test it on my phisical machine though, are you sure you tested it on the hyper-v guest?

Comment: That said, I made some modification to the test app so that it shows the normal processor performance counter, and it gives me a different reading, but not always "0" (not even always lower). I just can't figure it out: [another screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/GKR57wO.png) . It may be the host's CPU usage? I can't really check right now (don't have direct access to the host for measuring)

Comment: Here's the code for the test app... it's not pretty and not good, but I made it quick, just to try (it's a winforms app): http://pastebin.com/wibdGh45

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I run this on my 'remote office' which is a hyper-v virtual machine. Here you can see how I am running it: http://img.techguy.ws/di/G6LH/cpu.png  As you can see from the printscreen, they are virtual processors. What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: Oh, wow, my bad, I'm embarrased. I was actually testing it in a Hyper-V **host**, not guest (sorry, I thought I was RDPing to a different box). Everything works ok with the normal processor time count in a Win Server 2008 guest (and yes, I get `Category does not exist` for the Hyper-V counter)

Comment: @ErocM looking at your screenshot, you are creating a new `PerformanceCounter` when you write the next value. That's not how it's supposed to work. You create one `PerformanceCounter` and call `NextValue()` several times on that same object. Otherwise you are not letting it collect

Comment: Ah, ok. Once I have the values, do I need to do any computations between each `NextValue()`?

Comment: @ErocM no, not at all, just look at the code I pasted, it's that simple (I create the performance counters on the form's constructor, and just call `NextValue()` on a timer tick, to update the labels). Depending on the values given by the counter, you may need to make calculations on what is returned by `NextValue()` to make meaningful data out of it (for example, to get a process' CPU time the same way the task manager is showing it, you'll need to divide it by the processor count), but that depends on each specific counter and how you want to use that data

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to solve the specific problem, because as it was, it wasn't really answering the question. Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Use libvirt api to access host cpu usage, I have made an Python code to put all data into an csv file. Link for the Python code:  https://github.com/leonardo329cf/VMMeter-libvirt